# Shiny app not updating the data

Tags: r, shiny, run-app

I have a shiny page looking like that:

```
library(all my required packages)
source("that file that contains a function to grab my data")
data <- function_from_sourced_file()
server <- function(input, output)
ui <- shinyUI()
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Now this works fine but I need the shiny app to reflect the changes on said data and to do so I have to either rerun the `runApp()` function or `:w` the app.R file in vim. Is it possible to ask the shiny server to rerun the entire file each it is accessed?

thanks

Comment: As far as I can see [this blog entry](https://pghalliday.com/watch/shell/shiny/inotify-tools/guard/guard-livereload/guard-process/livereload/2015/02/17/reloading-a-shiny-application-on-source-changes.html), you have two options.

Answer (score 0):

One of the quick ways to do so is using [`reactivePoll`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactivePoll.html).

> reactivePoll

#### Value

A reactive expression that returns the result of valueFunc, and invalidates when checkFunc changes.

#### Description

Used to create a reactive data source, which works by periodically polling a non-reactive data source.

#### Example

[reactivePoll and reactiveFileReader](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/reactive-poll-and-file-reader.html)